# Recycle can not scroll inner ScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I hava a layout below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

the recyclerView using LinearLayoutManager, a item of recyclerView is another recyclerView which using GridLayoutManager, set the gridLayoutRecyclerView's height, but the gridLayoutRecyclerView can not scroll inner

Comment: but your code has only single scrollable view i.e. RecyclerView.

Comment: inner recyclerView is a item of recyclerView .

Comment: ,please update code completely with multiple RecyclerView and other information.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and also refer about this http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

After checking implementation, the reason appears to be the following. If `RecyclerView` gets put into a `ScrollView`, then during measure step its height is unspecified (because `ScrollView allows any height`) and gets equal to minimum height (as per implementation) which is apparently zero.

You have couple of options for fixing this:

- Set a certain height to RecyclerView
- Set ScrollView.fillViewport to true
- Or keep RecyclerView outside of ScrollView.

If RecyclerView height is not limited - which is the case when it's put into ScrollView - then all Adapter's views have enough place vertically and get created all at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is my out recyclerView's layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

then, a item of out recyclerView have another RecyclerView's which using GridLayoutManager, this is the code of the item below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/seatRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />
```

the seatRecyclerView can't not to scroll